# How do I remove this wire?

Tags: wiring

I've got to replace the wire and need to remove it from this case.  It looks like it locks in somehow.  Anyone have any ideas?

Idk what this type of enclosure (wire holder?) is called.

[image][image]

Comment: Grab you a precision flat head screwdriver and push up on the wire to release the locking tab on the wire connector from its position on the mold then use your flat head driver to push down the tab... at the top side of the terminal, not the back... Remember to replace the connector though, you dont want to re-use something ( wire connector ) that's been tampered with... I usually grind down a nail as flat as I can get it, It slides right in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plastic or nylon housings like this usually contain one-half (either male or female) of a push-on spade connector. Here's a female one, with no wire:

[image: here's a female one]

The male connector part slides into the female part between the female's rolled-together edges.

On the back face of this metal connector, you'll see a small tab of metal, pushed down at the left so its end is proud of the back surface of the clip. When assembled, the metal connector is pushed into the plastic or nylon housing — in this illustration, the open right end of the metal connector would be offered into the housing; if the housing were in the illustration, the housing would be slightly above and to the right of the metal connector.

When inserted into the housing, the tab drags along the inside face of the housing, and makes it difficult or impossible to withdraw the connedctor. The housing may have a hole or depression to receive the tab, making it ever harder to withdraw the connector from the housing.

Use a thin screwdriver or mechanic's pick between the metal connector and the housing, and push the tab back into alignment with the back of the connector. Holding the tab away from the housing, the connector should be able to be removed.

Other types of connectors (round pin, for instance) will often be mounted using the same sort of tab-that-jams. They're removed using the same technique.